# Except for protecting ears from cold air, does a woollen cap provide any other significant advantage in winters?

Tags: physiology

I have woollen earmuffs and they are really comfy. They do the job of protecting ears well enough and I don't really have to worry about hair statics as they only cover ears and not my hairs. But many times I do get advice against using those earmuffs and wear a woollen cap instead.
If protecting ears is the only reason of wearing caps than I don't think i should leave my earmuffs but most people, though unknown of any scientific proof, claim that caps have more of a advantage than just that. Is it really so?

Comment: I've never seen woolen headphones, and have a hard time imagining them, but there is a lot of practical iinformation about the value of insulating (not necessarily wool) head coverings, and their value in heat retention.  Of course it depends: for instance, if you have a thick head of long hair, a hat is going to be of less value than if you're bald.

Comment: Well I suppose that you are imagining some music type headphones with made out of wool. That's not it. They are just like a cap except that they don't cover your head, just your ears.

Comment: If you mean something like this https://www.amazon.com/Fleece-Ear-Muffs-Warmers-Earmuffs/dp/B01LZGPNAI they're called earmuffs, not headphones.  They keep your ears warm: a cap will keep the rest of your head warm, too.  And if it's really cold, you can wear both :-)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the correction. Never knew their actual name, even the shopkeepers in my region didn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article is what you need: http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20130708-is-most-heat-lost-from-your-head . Citing an excerpt from it:

> [H]aving your head immersed in cold water only adds 10% to your overall heat loss in a cold pool. And given that the head accounts for 7% to 9% of the body’s surface, that doesn’t seem excessive.
>
> But before you throw your collection of woolly hats in the bin, there’s another finding to bear in mind: when the head is allowed to get cold and the body is effectively insulated, the body’s core temperature drops a lot more rapidly than most people would expect.

In the end, wearing a woollen cap prevents the body's core temperature to drop too low. So if the rest of your body is well covered, you can skip the cap and put just your comfy headphones on; if, on the other hand, your clothes don't protect you well, putting a woollen hat on may be the easiest way to not feel cold.